# Read all PDFs in a directory (image)

Tags: python, pdf, operating-system, pypdf

I have attached an image to help show what I've done. I'm trying to write a program that will add a blank page to all PDFs in the directory that have an odd number of pages. However I can't seem to read all the PDFs in a directory.

The script I have works on a single PDF, but I have 1000's of these to do. Why can't I read all the PDFs in the user_input directory?

[image: Screenshot of code and error here]

code is here

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger
import os


user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")
files = os.listdir(user_input)

for file in files:
    print(file)
    pdfReader = PdfFileReader(open(files, 'rb'))
```

Comment: @MYGz sorry about that

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's okay you might be new here, Just learn the proper formatting techniques.

Answer (score 6):

Use following code. This code will give all list of pdf files from directory

```
import glob, os

def readfiles():
   os.chdir(path)
   pdfs = []
   for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
       print(file)
       pdfs.append(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to process every PDF file in the folder, you need a few things.

1. get to the right directory
2. get all files
3. get only the PDF files

OS is perfect for this. It can get all the files and then let you determine what to do with them. One problem I had (may be yours as well) was that my path had spaces in it, and os.chdir() was looking at the path ("something\ long\ with\ spaces/abcd/pdf\ folder") and was replacing all the spaces with "\ " meaning my final path was "something\ long\ with\ spaces/abcd/pdf\ folder" which is not a valid path. Removing the "\" from the original user input worked just fine. Let me know if you need any further help.

```
import os
os.chdir(raw_input("enter the path: ").replace("\\", ""))
print os.listdir(".")
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        print file
        process(file) # do whatever it is you need to here
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the .py file in the same directory as the pdfs? If not, you will need the full path to read the file not just the filename, which is returned by os.listdir

Comment: the .py file is in the same directory. for user input the path is C:\Python Projects\PDF (where the PDFs and the .py files are located)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `pathlib.Path`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def iterate_pdf_documents(folder_path):
    folder = Path(folder_path)
    pdf_files = folder.glob("**/*.pdf")

    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        process_single_file(pdf_file)


def process_single_file(path: Path):
    print(path)


# Usage example
current_dir = "."
iterate_pdf_documents(current_dir)
```